# Flask-RESTful with Flask-WTF forms integration

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-restful

I am using `Flask` with `Flask-RESTful`. I have POST method which gets data and I need to apply validation checks on it. 
My question is can i use `Flask-WTF` with that like `Django-Forms` for handling validations and checks?

What technique do you prefer for the scenario for `Signup` where i need to check if an Email already exists in the system?

Comment: I think you can use, it may depend on your needs too.

Comment: As `reqparse` is now deprecated, this question is now reopened. There is a need for another module, so webargs, wtforms? Can wtforms support GET as well? Compatibility of CRSF?

Answer (score 4):

The `reqparse` module of Flask-RESTful provides what you are looking for. By defining your own type of input fields, you can perform some validation operations. Here is an example from scratch:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


def is_email_valid(address):
    # Check if the e-mail address already exists in database.
    return True  # or False

def email(value):
    if not is_email_valid(value):
        raise ValueError("The e-mail address {} is already taken.".format(value))

    return value

class Users(Resource):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument('email', type=email, help='Signup email')

    def post(self):
        args = self.parser.parse_args()
        # Create the new user with args.items()
        return "user representation", 201


api.add_resource(Users, '/users')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If an argument fails to pass validation, the parser automatically responds with a 400 Bad Request.

You can find more information in the [documentation](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending.html#inputs) of Flask-RESTful.

Similarly, you can do this with WTForms :

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask.ext.restful import Api, Resource, abort
from wtforms import Form, fields, validators

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


# WTForms
def is_email_valid(address):
    # Check if the e-mail address already exists in database.
    return True  # or False

def user_email(form, field):
    if not is_email_valid(field.data):
        raise validators.ValidationError("The e-mail address {} is already taken.".format(field.data))

class UserForm(Form):
    email = fields.StringField('Email', [validators.Email(), user_email])


# Flask-RESTful
class Users(Resource):
    def post(self):
        form = UserForm(data=request.get_json())
        if form.validate():
            # Create the new user with form.populate_obj()
            pass
        else:
            abort(400)
        return "user representation", 201


api.add_resource(Users, '/users')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

However, even with the WTForms implementation, you have to define your form's fields unless you use a compatible ORM. For example, [some extensions](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ext.html#id3) of WTForms generate forms from models similarly to how it can be done for Django ORM models.

Comment: What if there are 20 fields you want to validate, i mean 20 fields are there which are required True, will u `add_argument` for each one of them?

Comment: Indeed, if you want to automatically map form's fields to model's fields like in Django, my solution is not what you are looking for. For that purpose, you can use WTForms and one of its extension to work with your ORM. Thus, the form's fields will be automatically generated, and depending of which ORM you use, the extension will attempt to guess at what validation might be wanted based on the field type. Nevertheless, you will still have to define a [custom validator](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validators.html#custom-validators)  to perform your checks on the email field.

Comment: I was trying to use those wtf forms, and when i checked request.form it was equal to `None` as request is coming from the API and it has json data. i get the params in `request.data` but when i pass the instance MyForm(request.data) it generates errors. do you know any example (i have searched too) that is using API + WTForms?

Comment: @Jack: I updated my answer to provide an example for WTForms.

Comment: Hmm. The "request" thing looked like a way forward but I just get an error saying it doesnt know what request is. 

This really isn't a practical api :/